# Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos, psql

I am using PostgreSQL12 on Cent0S8, and I am able to connect to PostgreSQL using the command:
`sudo -u postgres psql`

However, when I attempt to connect using:
`psql -U postgres -h localhost`

I recieve the following error:
`psql: error: count not connect to server: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"`

Every option is set to `trust` within my `pg_hba.conf` file, and I successfully restarted the server after making these changes.

Does anyone know of what I would need to change to be able to login using the `psql -U postgres -h localhost` command?

Comment: I'm going to say either  `auth` in the file has not been set to `trust` or you have more then one instance of Postgres running and you either modified the wrong `pg_hba.conf` file or connected to the wrong server. Also, try `psql -U postgres`, no host connection.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver I have attempted  to use `psql -U postgres`, and I receive the same error msg. When I use the `postgres -V` there is one instance displayed in the output, which is `PostgreSQL 12.1`

Comment: Try `ps ax | grep post`.

Comment: Can you post your pg_bha.conf file and the output of a system wide "find / -name pg_hba.conf" shell command?

Comment: connect using the first method, and then run `select * from pg_hba_file_rules;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are editing wrong hba file this should fix

1. Switch to postgres user on OS
2. run `psql`
   should be connected to PostgreSQL
3. run `show hba_file;`
   should be seeing to correct hba_file directory and edit that file.
4. reload postgresql

> lloyd@localhost:~$ sudo su - postgres
>
> postgres@localhost:~$ psql
>
> psql (13.1 (Ubuntu 13.1-1.pgdg18.04+1), server 12.5 (Ubuntu
> 12.5-1.pgdg18.04+1)) Type "help" for help.
>
> postgres=# show hba_file ;
>
> ---
>
> hba_file
>
> /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf (1 row)
>
> postgres=# select pg_reload_conf();

Last query should return true if it's not, there is an error in hba file so PostgreSQL won't refresh hba file. So you should look for error in file. Also you can look at logs. After reloading PostgreSQL, it shows you error with line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Yavuz, worked perfectly!